# Aurora RDS - difference between ConnectionAttempts and DatabaseConnections

Tags: amazon-rds, connections, aws-aurora, max-connections, amazon-rds-aurora

So I have [read this a few times](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-metrics.html) about these two metrics: ConnectionAttempts and DatabaseConnections.

Based on the above, is RDS rejecting lots of connections? Here are the graphs of these two metrics.

Or perhaps I have miss-understood?

[image]

The max-connections parameter is set to 1609 for each instance.